# Form validation of email id and password using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, web-development-server

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOSIQ.png)

I cannot understand what is going wrong with this code?
I need to validate `emailid` and `password` for the website I am making using Javascript.
The first alert is working properly as well as the alert in else,
only if's lert is not coming.

```
alert("hi")
const loginForm = document.getElementById("logform");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("logbut");
const emailid = loginForm.emailid.value;
const password = loginForm.password.value;

loginButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   if (emailid === "user@123" && password === "user") {
      alert("You have successfully logged in.");

    }else{
     alert("oh");
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to capture field values inside event listener. When page loads default values get populated in emailid and password. On button click they are not getting repopulated, they are having intial state only. Either observe value change in input fields or recapture form state in click event.

Comment: please post **code** in the question, not a picture of code (takes longer to post a picture of code than it does to copy/paste code in a question, not sure why so many people get this wrong)

Comment: `const emailid = loginForm.emailid.value` should be just `const emailid = loginForm.emailid` and then inside your event listener check for `emailid.value` and do the same for the password, that way you are checking against the current value and not the initial one

Comment: Yes this worked @SaymoinSam Thankyou  so much.Can you explain a bit what was going wrong? Why we cannot use value in start?

Comment: @KhushiZawar *Why we cannot use value in start?*, well because when you assign `const emailid = loginForm.emailid.value` the `emailid` will hold the current value of that element and it depends on the place you write that  in, so in your case it was the global scope and that will get executed at the beginning,so it will hold the initial value of that input, but instead you should get the value each time the user interacts with your input by assigning `const emailid = loginForm.emailid` to the element and then get the value each time you want to check against `if(emailid.value === "something")`

Comment: So what if I wrote this part of code  const emailid = loginForm.emailid.value;
const password = loginForm.password.value; inside the evenlistener function?

Comment: @KhushiZawar, sorry for the late reply, I was at work, and yes if you write that part of code inside the event listener, that will also work